# Just installed ProText. Command paths all "unknown"

Tags: errors, texstudio, protext

Installation went fine but I haven't been able to view a document. I have created and saved a sample document. If I click "build and compile" (the two green arrows) it says "Can't find C:\Users..." though that is the correct file path. "Compile" (single green arrow) does nothing. Clicking the Adobe icon opens Adobe in an external window but then says "file could not be found".

Under Options>Configure TexStudio>Commands tab, all fields say "unknown" except the External PDF Viewer one ""C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "?am.pdf"

Comment: I am very new to this site and LaTeX in general. I recently installed TeXstudio and am having the exact same problem as mentioned by Madiha above. If anyone has ideas or suggestions that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I just uninstalled protext and installed miktext instead. It comes with a very simple editor but it works fine for me.